# Windows 8 - Save Image in XAML as local file ( inside Application folder )

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my Windows store application, i am displaying a picture using *Image* control in XAML. Source of the Image control is set, code wise using ***WriteableBitmap***. I am trying to send this image as *attachment* in *email*. Is there any easy way for that? I am trying to save that image locally( within application ) and attach that saved image to email. But not able to save locally. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code.

bitmap = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(dataCanvas);
image.Source = bitmap;

dataCanvas is a Canvas control consists of two images, one place above another. Actually i have to place a sunglass top of users face and display it as another image in xaml. Also email that image.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions.cs) class in WinRT XAML Toolkit for all the `SaveToFile()` extension methods you can use to save your `WriteableBitmap`.

The core one is this:

```
public static async Task SaveToFile(
    this WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap,
    StorageFile outputFile,
    Guid encoderId)
{
    Stream stream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

    using (var writeStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, writeStream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
            (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight,
            96,
            96,
            pixels);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();

        using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the encoder ID using an overload of the method:

```
public static async Task<StorageFile> SaveToFile(
    this WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap,
    StorageFolder storageFolder,
    string fileName,
    CreationCollisionOption options = CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
{
    StorageFile outputFile =
        await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            fileName,
            options);

    Guid encoderId;

    var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

    if (new[] { ".bmp", ".dib" }.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId;
    }
    else if (new[] { ".tiff", ".tif" }.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.TiffEncoderId;
    }
    else if (new[] { ".gif" }.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId;
    }
    else if (new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".jpe", ".jfif", ".jif" }.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
    }
    else if (new[] { ".hdp", ".jxr", ".wdp" }.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegXREncoderId;
    }
    else //if (new [] {".png"}.Contains(ext))
    {
        encoderId = BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId;
    }

    await writeableBitmap.SaveToFile(outputFile, encoderId);

    return outputFile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Filip,

Shall i know what is the value i have to pass as (Guid) encoderId to this method? So far i am passing these values,               StorageFile targetFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("testImage" + Random + ".jpg");         
           await SaveToFile(bitmap, targetFile, Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);                 An image is created in target location but only foreground image(ie sunglass) can be seen, no background(user's face). Any help?

Comment: If you look at the link - there is a method that figures out the right encoder based on file extension, but you can also provide that manually - check the [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) class documentation for properties that define the different encoder guids.

Comment: Edited above comment, Any ways?

Comment: If i add an image in application folder as background, everything works properly. Image with both user's face and sunglass can be displayed in xaml and saved localy. But if i use image captured from device's camera, balck screen is displayed in background. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Various media are not included in `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()` result unfortunately - only basic static `UIElements`. You can capture the frame manually and swap out the live camera preview with an image for the duration of the visual tree render.

Comment: :( Is compressing the image obtained from camera will help? Any other  replacement for ( bitmap = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(dataCanvas); ) will really help :)

Comment: No, if you want an image from the camera - you need to capture it yourself - it's not that hard. Combining it together should be fairly easy too. Just put an `Image` element in front of the camera preview one, put the captured bitmap as its source when doing the screen capture and then render the visual tree. Afterwards - switch `Visibility` of that `Image` to `Collapsed`.

Comment: Good idea. But i am using inbuilt camera which is not within app. As only easy way, i am upgrading OS as Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then. You first said you are using an image captured from the camera and then you say it's not within the app. It seems like it doesn't matter then than the image comes from the camera, right? Are you using just an `Image` control to display it?

Answer (score -1):

Any subclass of `BitmapSource` (including `WritableBitmap`) can be passed to a [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  A `BitmapEncoder` takes a `Stream` to which the encoded JPEG, PNG or other image is written.

You can then use a mailer library to reference the stream used by the encoder, or use the Share contract, and pass the stream directly.

Example:

```
var bitmap = new WritableBitmap();

// ... draw your bitmap

var tempPath = // path to where you want to save (probably in your appx temp);
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

encoder.Frames.Add(bitmap);

using (var fs = new FileStream(tempPath))
{
    encoder.Save(fs);
}

// use the image saved to tempPath
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871370.aspx
```

Comment: Window store apps run in box environment and does not provide system level access so you cannot use `Path.GetTempPath()`.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, which is in no way related to the requirement of saving a `BitmapSource` to disk.  One can easily insert the appropriate calls to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder` as a substitute.  If we are being pedantic, `WritableBitmap` doesn't even exist in WinRT...

Comment: I think then you must provide solution that is appropriate for WinRT.